# Google keeps old and deleted contacts list?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have used Gmail for many years, and during this time I have deleted a lot of email messages and contacts.

I discovered that when I use some services (for example, DropBox) to invite my friends by my Gmail account, Google also suggests to me contacts I deleted a long time ago!

Why? Where is Dropbox finding these old contacts?

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you can take off auto-additions for contacts as explained in the Google support page [Creating contacts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8933?hl=en).

For the contacts you already have, feel free to clean those Google contacts up by clicking on the **Mail** button in the top right of Gmail and go to contacts (Do check out both **MyContacts** and **OtherContacts** within your groups).

Lastly, if you're interested in making sure you have all the contact information for your contacts, you might consider trying out the solution my company has come up with to automatically update your Gmail address book: http://writethat.name/

Comment: That's not my problem. When I use the invite function from some web services (like DropBox), and it connects itself to my google account, I see old contacts removed from my phone book in the past! ;)

Comment: Huh... that's really odd.  They might have a cached version of your contacts (which might be a security issue) or you might have these contacts still in <b>Other Contacts</b>.  Did you check there?

Comment: No, there isn't in "Other contacts", I suppose Google cashes all contacts all over my emailing history!!!